# Input file in CodeName One

Tags: file, input, filesystems, codenameone

I read about loading images from Gallery, is very simple:

```
Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener() { 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
   {
                        //Implement
   }
}, GALLERY_IMAGE);
```

But i couldn't find something alike to load a file from the system using some input box for the user to look for it in the local system, just like an `<input type="text" name="fileLoaderBtn">` of [html](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp). Can i do this in CodeName One?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike HTML you can actually access any arbitrary file accessible to your app directly without the need for a file picker by using the [FileSystemStorage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html) API.

You can use the [FileTree](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/FileTree.html) to show a tree of the files or present them in any way you see fit.

Notice that mobile OS's restrict your access to the full file system so you can only access files that are exposed to your app.